# C# change image when sound stops playing

Tags: audio, while-loop, state, soundplayer

I am making a .wav player application in which I have a button to play the loaded .wav

So if the sound is playing a "pause" button will be showed and when it stops a "play" button will be showed.

currently using this:

```
        using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(label1.Text))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Form1.Properties.Resources.play_button;
            try
            {
                player.Play();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File has been moved." + "\n" + "Please relocate it now!");
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to make it?
If it is how to make it?
Source if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may need something other than sound player... I can't see anything on msdn that'll let u pause or catch an onpause event... try using the mediaplayer class?